# List doesn't update list after I added new item

Tags: angular

I have a list of todo items and each item has the possibility to be deleted or modified. When I do any of those two the item gets updated in the list straight away.

When I add a new item to the list the list doesn't reload and I have to refresh the page to see the new item. I've read up about the topic and implemented a trackElement method but it doesn't seem to work.

Is it a problem that I have a separate component for the dialog where I create a new item?

todo-list-component.ts:

```
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {

    todoList: Array<any>;

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
    }



    @Input() toDoData = {taskName: '', taskCompleted: false, date: Date};


    ngOnInit() {
        this.getToDos();
    }

    getToDos() {
        this.todoList = [];
        this.todoService.getToDos().subscribe((data: []) => {
            console.log('Todo List get Todos ', data);
            this.todoList = data;
        });
    }

    delete(id) {
        this.todoService.deleteToDo(id)
            .subscribe(res => {
                    this.getToDos();
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
    }

    completed(id, todo) {
        todo.taskCompleted = !todo.taskCompleted;
        this.todoService.updateToDo(id, todo)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.getToDos();
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    openDialog(todo): void {
        console.log('TodoList Dialog Open: ', todo);
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditToDoDialogComponent, {
            data: {
                todoUpdate: todo,
            }
        });

        console.log('Edit Dialog:' + todo.toString());

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            this.getToDos();
            console.log('The dialog was closed');
        });
    }

    trackElement(index: number, element: any) {
        return element ? element.id : null;
    }
}
```

Header component with the openDialog():

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
    }


    openDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewToDoDialogComponent, {});

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('The dialog was closed');
        });
    }
}
```

And finally the new todo dialog:

```
export class NewToDoDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() toDoData = {taskName: '', extraNote: '', taskCompleted: false, dueDate: Date};

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewToDoDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private todoService: TodoService) {
    }


    ngOnInit() {
    }

    saveToDo() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
        this.todoService.addToDo(this.toDoData)
            .subscribe((result) => {
                this.todoService.getToDos();
            });
    }
}
```

Todo Service:

```
export class TodoService {
    public API = 'http://localhost:8080/';

    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    };


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        const body = res;
        return body || {};
    }

    getToDos(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.API + 'todos').pipe(
            map(this.extractData));
    }

    getToDo(id): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.API + 'todos/' + id).pipe(
            map(this.extractData));
    }

    addToDo(todo): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.API + 'todos', JSON.stringify(todo), this.httpOptions).pipe(
            tap((todo) => console.log(`added todo w/ id=${todo.id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<any>('addTodo'))
        );
    }

    updateToDo(id, todo): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(this.API + 'todos/' + id, JSON.stringify(todo), this.httpOptions).pipe(
            tap(_ => console.log(`updated todo id=${id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateTodo'))
        );
    }

    deleteToDo(id): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete<any>(this.API + 'todos/' + id, this.httpOptions).pipe(
            tap(_ => console.log(`deleted todo id=${id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<any>('deleteToDo'))
        );
    }

    private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
            // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
            console.error(error); // log to console instead
            // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
            console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
            // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
            return of(result as T);
        };
    }
}
```

This is how the app looks like if it helps:
https://snag.gy/689q7z.jpg

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: If I see this right, you never add the new toDo to your `this.todoList` from TodoListComponent. In addition, can you post the code of your TodoService too?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added the service file. I can see from the console that the list has more items than there in the list.

Comment: if you use this code this.todoService.getToDos().subscribe(todo=>{this.todoData = todo;}); instead of this.todoService.getToDos(); inside saveTodo function it should work.

Comment: That didn't work. I just need to call the function getToDos() from the todo-list component.